# How to paste a row of data from one google sheet to another sheet in a different workbook

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

After running this code:

```js
function SendData() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("URL"); // sss = source spreadsheet
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Verify'); // ss = source sheet
  var rangeToCopy = ss.getRange("B28:Q28");
  var copiedData = rangeToCopy.getValues();
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("URL"); // tss = target spreadsheet
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('log'); // ts = target sheet
  ts.appendRow(copiedData);
   
  
}
```

The script writes to the target sheet a random value that looks like this, in cell A1:

**[Ljava.lang.Object;@70cb5117**

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getValues()` method gets a 2D array.  Each inner array represents one row.  Each element of each inner array represents one cell.  The `appendRow()` method takes a 1D array.  Because your range is only one row of data, then you could convert the 2D array to a 1D array, and use `appendRow()`

```
copiedData = copiedData.toString().split(",");//convert 2D to 1D
ts.appendRow(copiedData);
```

If you were getting more than 1 row of data, then you could not use `appendRow()`.  You would need to use `getRange(startRow,startColumn, numberOfRows, numberOfColumns).setValues(2D_Array)`

It would look like this:

```
var lastRow = ts.getLastRow();
ts.getRange(lastRow+1,1,copiedData.length,copiedData[0].length).setValues(copiedData);
```